# How to enter BIOS before Windows 8.1 start-up?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

I have an Acer Aspire v5 laptop with Windows 8.1 installed.  Windows started up with a message saying it was Diagnosing your PC and it will take about 10 hours to show me the next page.  My question is how to enter the BIOS and change the boot order simply and without repairing my Windows 8.1 because I want to format the drive and start with a new Windows 7.  I have tried the F2 and DEL but Windows 8.1 is too fast.

Comment: -1  You mention the OS in your title but the OS is irrelevant. The fast boot up of the BIOS is what gives you a very short time

Comment: If you computer boots then you can boot to the advanced startup menu to access the UEFI configuration otherwise if 3 failed attempts will automatically display it.  You no longer access the UEFI/BIOS through a keyshort if you have a device that uses fast boot.  There are several questions on how to access Avanced Startup so I won't repeat the infomration

Answer (score -1):

F2 is usual on Acers but it might also be F10. Keep tapping F2 repeatedly after switch-on until a screen appears.

Answer (score -1):

**Completely shut down** Windows 8, rather than use (default) hybrid shutdown, before trying to reboot, because startup after hybrid shutdown may bypass BIOS setup. To force immediate full shutdown, you can open a Command Prompt and enter **shutdown /s /f /t 0**. You may need to hold <kbd>F2</kbd> before pressing power, since reboot is *fast*.

See this [thread from the Acer community](http://community.acer.com/t5/2014-Archives/How-do-I-access-the-BIOS-on-a-Acer-Aspire-V3-571G-9636/td-p/13751) on accessing BIOS.